# Почему click на кнопке input отрабатывает, а submit нет?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, form

Есть форма, которую хочу заставить отправлять данные с помощью `ajax` и получать сообщение об успешной отправке, но не могу понять: почему `click` отрабатывает, а `submit` нет. [вот фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/vGAsL/64/)

```js
$('.confirmation').click(function() {
  console.log("click is");
});
$('.confirmation').submit(function() {
  console.log("submit is");
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/system/wpacert',
    data: $("#form_id").serializeArray(),
    success: function(data) {
      $(".confirmation").magnificPopup({
        items: {
          src: '#confirmation',
          type: 'inline'
        }
      });
      alert('sucsess'); // проверяем работу скрипта в случае успеха 
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('fail'); // проверяем работу скрипта в случае неудачи 
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/master/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<script src="http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgithub.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/master/dist/magnific-popup.css">
<form id="form_id" action="/system/wpacert" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="certform">
  <input type="text" value="Имя" />
  <input type="password" value="Пароль" />
  <div>Сертификат:
    <input type="file" name="cert1" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="confirmation" type="submit" value="Добавить" />
  </div>
</form>
<div id="confirmation" class="mfp-hide">
  <h2>Результат</h2>
  <p>Имя</p>
  <p>Пароль</p>
  <p>Сертификат №</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Потому, что сабмитеть надо форму, а не инпут)) `$('form').submit(function() {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sumbit нужно указывать на форму а не на кнопку**

```
 $('#form_id').submit(function(e) {
      //что бы страница не перезагружалась
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("submit is");
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/system/wpacert',
        data: $("#form_id").serializeArray(),
        success: function(data) {
          $(".confirmation").magnificPopup({
            items: {
              src: '#confirmation',
              type: 'inline'
            }
          });
          alert('sucsess'); // проверяем работу скрипта в случае успеха 
        },
        error: function() {
          alert('fail'); // проверяем работу скрипта в случае неудачи 
        }
      });
    });
```